# What is the new method for the deprecated backgroundColor

Tags: flutter, dart

I was following an old flutter tutorial in which backgroundColor was used.
Here is what I wrote following the tutorial:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My app',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      ),
      home: const Text("My UI page"),
    );
  }
}
```

The myBackgroundColor is a const in another file consiting all the colors for the app.
What should I write in theme to apply myBackgroundColor?

The flutter docs say backgroundColor is deprecated and use colorScheme.background instead. But when using colorScheme.background I get an error sayind undefined name 'colorScheme'.

Comment: colorScheme is a property of ThemeData... do you have a themeData in hand?

Comment: Also, for nearly anything of value, I now use package:flex_color_scheme, which is concise but thorough.

Answer (score 0):

As it states

> 'backgroundColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use
> colorScheme.background instead.

**Try**

```dart
theme: ThemeData.from(
  colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
    background: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```