Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'
I want to run one of my old projects and while running I'm getting this error:

Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.

'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/Android/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
TextStyle(color: confirmTextColor ?? theme.backgroundColor),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Script 'C:\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1629
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I already tried to find where is that backgroundColor in 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' but nothing in it. I didn't find backgroundColor in whole theme_data.dart file.
How to solve this?

If you want to set the background color for your app using a ThemeData, you should use the backgroundColor property of the Scaffold widget, which is where you typically define the background color for your app.

@DroidFlutter I don't want to set background color for my app I just want to run the app but while running I'm getting this error and In that app I never set background color anywhere.

@DroidFlutter I think you didn't get it what I want to ask. I didn't set background color anywhere in my app. I found similar issue on Reddit but I can't find solution.

While opening old project you got ->  Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'. Am I right?

Okay I have solved this error, the error is coming from a package. I have used Get package in my old app which is outdated. I have just updated it,
From
get: ^4.6.5

To
get: ^4.6.6


It looks like somewhere in your project you there is a
TextStyle(color: confirmTextColor ?? theme.backgroundColor)
You can't use this theme.backgroundColor anymore. It looks like it might actually not be in your own code but in a package called flutter_tools. It seems this package hasn't been updated for 4 years, and it's now simply not compatible with the most recent flutter version anymore. The only way to get it to build again is to downgrade your flutter version, or to remove the flutter_tools package from your project.

Thank you for your response I didn't know that theme.backgroundColor is deprecated.

So what is the new syntax for it?

@SalmanNaghori see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380986/what-is-the-new-method-for-the-deprecated-backgroundcolor

The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.

@SalmanNaghori the linked question gave the answer. need to use colorScheme.surface instead.

The backgroundColor property in ThemeData was removed in newer Flutter versions. Replace theme.backgroundColor with theme.colorScheme.background to resolve the issue:
TextStyle(color: confirmTextColor ?? theme.colorScheme.background)

This will ensure compatibility with the updated Flutter theme system.

Updating the Get package to the latest version resolved my issue. You can get the latest version here https://pub.dev/packages/get.
